# What are the orange dots?

Tags: shadow-warrior-2

There are quite a few small orange dots appearing on the map at Wang Cave. Some of them are at the smithing area and another one is in the above stairs of his apartment.

What are these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orange dots seem to indicate an object you can interact with at some point but are not ready to be interacted with yet. For example there is an orange dot on the forge and in one of the side missions you have to destroy something in it by interacting with it.